# SDL render box2d on the right position

Tags: c++, sdl, box2d

For many hours I tried to render the car from [this tutorial](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/top-down-car) in sdl. But for some reason I just can't render it in the right spot. Im trying to let the car collide with a staticbody (a tree its also rendered), but the collision is never on the right spot.

In my car I made a function that returns the tires so I can render them as reference point (i know i render the body of the car right if it's between the tires).

To render the car I made the following code.

```
void World::drawObject(float nwidth, float nheight, float nx, float ny, float nangle)
{
    float angle = nangle * RADTODEG;
    //To get the center
    float x = nx - (nwidth / 2);
    float y = ny + (nheight / 2);

    //- before y to mirror axis
    SDL_Rect drawingRect = { x * scale, - y * scale, nwidth * scale, nheight * scale };
    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderTarget, textureCar, NULL, &drawingRect, transfrom(angle), NULL, SDL_FLIP_VERTICAL);
}

void World::drawCar(){

    SDL_RenderClear(renderTarget);

    drawObject(6, 10, myCar->getB2DPosition().x, myCar->getB2DPosition().y, myCar->getAngleB2D());
    drawObject(6, 10, myTree->getB2DPosition().x, myTree->getB2DPosition().y, myTree->getAngleB2D());

    //get all tires and render them
    std::vector<TDTire*> tires = myCar->getTires();
    for (int i = 0; i < tires.size(); i++)
    {
        drawObject(0.5, 1.25, tires[i]->getX(), tires[i]->getY(), 0);
    }
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderTarget);
}

//used to get the mirrored angle.
int World::transfrom(float dgrs)
{

    int add360 = dgrs + 360;
    int newAngle = 0;
    int gradenBox2d = add360 % 360;
    if (gradenBox2d < 90)
    {
        int temp = 90 - gradenBox2d;
        newAngle = 90 + temp;
    }
    if (gradenBox2d < 180)
    {
        int temp = gradenBox2d - 90;
        newAngle = 90 - temp;
    }
    if (gradenBox2d < 270)
    {
        int temp = 270 - gradenBox2d;
        newAngle = 270 + temp;
    }
    else{
        int temp = gradenBox2d - 270;
        newAngle = 270 - temp;
    }
    int newNewAngle = newAngle % 360;
    return newNewAngle;
}
```

With my current code the car is always behind the front tires.

When I call getB2Position and getAngle i return

```
return m_body->GetPosition();
return m_body->GetAngle();
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I used an arrow as image to show the direction.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: It will take a pen and pencil to figure the math of this out, but if you're lazy like me, one option could be to pre-render a car to a buffer texture and rotate that.

Comment: @LogicStuff I did alot of drawings, this was the best result i could come up with. thanks for the hint I wil look into prerendering to a buffer texture.

Comment: No offence, of course :)

Comment: @LogicStuff no offense taken, any help is welcome at this point. :-)

Comment: @LogicStuff do you have more info about prerendering to a buffer texture?

Comment: Not really, it just came off the top of my head, and I haven't been working with SDL for a long time. How did it go?